# ThemeKit themeid flag not overriding config.yml on theme watch command

Tags: command-line-interface, shopify

In the main `config.yml` the `themeid` is set to the global variable `$THEMEKIT_THEME_ID`, which is a value that starts with `799*********`, I want to override this value using the `themeid` flag to another theme value, `805**********`. However, when I do `theme watch` with a different `themeid`, it still uses the one from the `config.yml`.

[image]

I've tried different option formats like `--themeid 805*******`, `--themeid="805**********"`, `--themeid "805**********`. Nothing works, it keeps using the global themeid for the development environment. Any ideas?

Comment: Running the command `theme watch --themeid=1` (or whatever the theme ID is) _should_ do the trick and works for me when I use it

Comment: @DaveB It should, but my themekit default development environment config references the theme ID set by an environment variable. `--themeid` doesn't appear to override that value for some reason.

Comment: Hmm. Are you able to share an example of what your config.yml setup looks like?

Comment: @DaveB I ended up opening a bug ticket in the ThemeKit repo. A version of the config.yml is shown there https://github.com/Shopify/themekit/issues/674

Comment: Yeah, looks like you've hit a bug/edge case in ThemeKit and checking in with the developers is the way to go. Good luck!

Comment: @DaveB Thanks, I'll close this question when ThemeKit pushes a fix.

Answer (score 0):

**Temp Fix**

Set the global variable for a single command.

[image]